# ESLint rule for arrow function requiring return type

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I'm having below arrow function in my angular project:

```
this.httpClient.get('url').subscribe((response)=>{

});
```

In the above code ESLint should throw an error for not specifying return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the rule [@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md). You need to set the option `allowTypedFunctionExpressions` to `false`. If you are using .eslintrc:

```json
"@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
  "error",
  {
    "allowTypedFunctionExpressions": false
  }
]
```